# VMWare API to get events

Tags: java, api, groovy, vmware, soapui

I need to fetch events from a virtual machine in Groovy. I found [this](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-10010) java class that apparently lists events and allows me to filter them but it's getting too complex and I don't think this is what I really need. What I'm looking at is a java/groovy version of the CLI call:

```
$vc_events = Get-VIEvent -Server $vm | where {$_.CreatedTime -gt $lastEventTime -and $_.EventTypeId -like "com.SomepPlugin.event.*"}
```

My problem with the class I found is that SoapUI, which is where I'm using Groovy, doesn't like to use imported jars in its groovy script. It always fails to recognize the classes and packages I try to import in the groovy script even if the jar file is in the appropriate extensions folder. I'm going to have to write a Groovy class similar to the one in the link above to make it work and I'd like to keep it simple.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can't you just copy&past the entire source into a groovy file? i think groovy just eats java syntax

Comment: p.s. why not make a shell script and call that from java?

Comment: @kritzikratzi It won't compile as-is copied into a Groovy file as it has `do...while` loops that are not available in Groovy. However you should just be able to compile it to a class and then call it from Groovy...

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite stuff from powershell to soapUI. Executing a shell script destroys the purpose. And the code in that class isn't fitting my purpose in the first place - this i realized later. Since it's a demo, i'll have to rewrite all those classes in groovy and then use them in my groovyscript in soapUI which is overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your PowerCLI command (or even GUI actions) against [doublecloud-proxy](http://www.doublecloud.org/doublecloud-proxy/) and it will spit out java for you.

Comment: This is useful. But it doesn't catch PowerCLI commands from PowerCLI. It only catches requests that are made through VSphere, which doesn't let me add a filter. Guess I could just add the filter into the java code. Thanks!